# Status Code: Conflict; Reason: Subscription quota has been exceeded when registering subscription in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

When trying to register a subscription we get the following error back from [POST] https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

[Status Code: Conflict; Reason: Subscription quota has been exceeded]

The code works for some tenants but some stopped working the other day, have not been able to find any documentation about what the cause is.

The resource we are subscribing on is: "/communications/callRecords"

Answer (score 1):

According [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#teams-resource-limitations), the quota for `/communications/callRecords` is 100 total subscriptions per organization.

Resources:

[Azure AD resource limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#azure-ad-resource-limitations)